# Boost filesystem tutorial won't compile

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks

I try to compile the boost filesystem [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/example/tut1.cpp) in Code::Blocks
And it comes up these errors

```
Linking console executable: bin\Debug\Boost fs tut1.exe
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
D:/Documents/Coding/Libs/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
D:/Documents/Coding/Libs/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
D:/Documents/Coding/Libs/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5boost11filesystem34path7codecvtEv':
D:/Documents/Coding/Libs/boost/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp:388: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `convert':
D:/Documents/Coding/Libs/boost/boost/filesystem/v3/path_traits.hpp:113: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const&)'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `file_size':
D:/Documents/Coding/Libs/boost/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:366: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::detail::file_size(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
6 errors, 0 warnings
```

I'm running it on windows 7 with Code::Blocks version 10.5, G++ version 4.4.1, and boost version 1.47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chunk of Boost.System lives in a library that is built seperately. It is not all header files. You have to build it and link to it.

See [Linking Boost Library in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408619/problem-linking-boost-library-in-linux) for one example (linux) and http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef (CodeBlocks)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I rebuilt the Library using the Directions for CodeBlocks and it worked!(Apparently the build tool that comes with Boost builds for VC++ and puts it in an obscure directory)