# unresolved symbols from boost filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I am using boost 1_53 libraries with VS10.
I am getting many unresolved symbols during linking. like the following:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost_1_53_0::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > &,class std::codecvt<unsigned short,char,int> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost_1_53_0@@YAXPEBD0AEAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@AEBV?$codecvt@GDH@5@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost_1_53_0::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > &,class std::codecvt<unsigned short,char,int> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost_1_53_0@@YAXPEBDAEAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@AEBV?$codecvt@GDH@5@@Z)
```

I checked /LIBPATH is set correctly also "boost_1_53_0_filesystem-mt.lib" is coming in link line.
i used dumpbin to find symbol in "lib" its coming like:

```
00000036  REL32 00000000 515  ?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost_1_53_0@@YAXPEBD0AEAV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@AEBV?$codecvt@_WDH@5@@Z (void __cdecl boost_1_53_0::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &,class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> const &))
```

Is this parameter change causing issue?

**EDIT:**
I like to add more details:
Previously i was using boost 1_48 which was working fine.
I found that in boost 1_48 symbols under path_traits ends with **@GDH@5@@Z** whicle in boost 1_53 its ending with **@_WDH@5@@Z**
But still It trying to search synbol end with **@GDH@5@@Z**
This can cause error?
If so why its taking that symbols?

Comment: if boost library is built in release mode, you can only link in release mode

Comment: @Thomas: i am using it in release mode only

Comment: Then, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075315/boost-filesystem-tutorial-wont-compile

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've built every possible permutation of the Boost libraries, it is necessary to make sure that your compiler settings match the settings used to build Boost.

The relevant settings are:

- debug vs. release
- statically linked runtime vs. DLL
- single-threaded vs. multi-threaded

The name `boost_1_53_0_filesystem-mt.lib` implies that the Boost libraries were built release mode, multi-threaded, DLL runtime.

Is that how you're building your project?

Comment: Thx for support.   
i build boost 1_48 that time it works fine problem started with same code once i started using boost 1_53
i build boost 1_53 same way i built boost 1_48
I hv edited question with more details

Answer (score 0):

Right click on 
->properties
->in general tab 
check whether

> Common Language Runtime support = "No Common Language Runtime support"

-> in c/C++ -> code generation
check whether

> Runtime library Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

finally in the menu bar go to 
-> tools -> options -> project and solutions -> VC++ directories -> library files 
check whether you have given the complete path where you boost librarus are usually

> "\boost_1_53\stage\lib"

NOTE: the setting paths are mentioned for VS2008

Comment: Thx for support.
I checked settings it looks fine

Comment: @Abhi so did u figure it out or the u still stuck ?

Comment: oh wait i noticed that you have build the boost as Multi-threaded so did u try changing the Runtime library to  Multi-threaded (/MT) ?

Comment: thx for support i finally got what the problem is
actually its causing due to QT (I never thought so)
i build boost with /Zc:wchar_t flag while the QT is buils with /Zc:wchar_t- which causing error

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are not using 64 bit compiled boost libraries instead of 32 bit ones (and vice versa). It's what happened for me while using boost::filesystem.

Comment: This should be a comment